# Why is my frontend not receiving socket.io events

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have a fun little project going on with mineflayer to make a webgui to control a minecraft console client. I cant seem to catch socket.io events on the frontend js.

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const { botJump,
    botForward,
    botBackward,
    botLeft,
    botRight,
    botChat,
    botDerpMode,
    botMove,
    botConnect } = require("./botFunctions");
const botFunctions = require("./botFunctions");
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`New connection established on namespace: ${socket.nsp.name}`);
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});
```

botfunctions.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer");
const pathfinder = require("mineflayer-pathfinder").pathfinder;
const { GoalNear } = require("mineflayer-pathfinder").goals;
const { io } = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');


let bot;


socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to server');
});

bot.on('messagestr', (msg) => {
   //console.log(msg);
   socket.emit('chat message', msg );
});
```

Frontend JS

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io();
    console.log(socket);
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
    socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log(socket.connected); // true
    });
    </script>
```

So obviously a lot of unnecessary code is left out only stuff involved with socket.io.
I receive the console.log from server.js with message: "blah". but nothing happens on he front end.

Comment: The only possibility to emit events is in `bot.on('messagestr', ..`?

Comment: @qrsngky Thats the only thing i want to emmit, bot.on('messagestr')... is an event that fires for every chat message in game, and the goal is to show that chat clientside